# Elasticsearch mapping not created

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I am trying to create an index from the official ES guide.

[image: Creation of index]

The index is created with status 200, but it has no mapping as you can see in the picture below. Calling a GET for http://localhost:9201/test/_mapping/type1 returns 404 Not Found.

[image: Getting the index]

I am running Elasticsearch 5.6.6 locally on port 9201 and for the query execution I use Fiddler 4.

What am I missing ?

Comment: You probably want http://localhost:9200/test/_mapping/type1.  See [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/indices-get-mapping.html).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I've made a mistake in the order, I am sorry, but it doesn't work either ... I've also tried GET /_mapping for all the indices but no result.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this against a 5.6.6 Docker container: `curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/test -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "mappings": { "type1": { "properties": { "field1": { "type": "text" } } } } }' && curl http://localhost:9200/test/_mappings/type1` produces `{"acknowledged":true,"shards_acknowledged":true,"index":"best"}{"best":{"mappings":{"type1":{"properties":{"field1":{"type":"text"}}}}}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that in the PUT you are actually passing the body of the json request? It seems that you are doing a PUT with an empty body, that create only the index and not the mapping.

Comment: You are right ... I was putting my query into the wrong form in Fiddler ... I didn't even realized that there were a second form which was actually Request body. Thank you very much